# angular.mock.inject outside beforeEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

How do I use angular.mock.inject outside a beforeEach block?

I am trying to setup a file with all the mocks for our app's services, the methods in these mocks will be jasmine spies, that will return a promise with an empty object. This is `mockService.js`:

```
define(['angular','angular.mocks'], function () {

    return {
        UserService: {
            read: jasmine.createSpy('UserService.read()')
        }
    }
});
```

To follow the DRY principle, I have these mocks defined as a require.js module, and my spec file will require this module. This is `UsersController.spec.js`:

```
define([

    'angular',
    'mockServices',
    'angular.mocks',
    'app/app.module'
]
```

But, I am unable to have `mockServices.UserService.read` return a promise like so:

```
UserService: {
    read: jasmine.createSpy('TokensService.read()').and.callFake(function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve({});
        return deferred.promise;
    })
}
```

Because $q is undefined. I have used angular.mock.inject in the beforeEach block to get access to $q.

I have tried IIFE'ing the function that inject returns, and I get an error that mentions currentSpec.$modules, but I don't know what that is.

How do I get access to $q outside beforeEach?

Comment: Get `$q` inside a before each, then store it in a local variable in your test or wherever.

Comment: tried it. setting up mockService.UserService.read happens before a beforeEach, so i can't grab $q from inside there.